# Consuming data of restAPI using Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am calling below restAPI using node JS.

[image]

I am using below code.

```
var Request = require("request");
Request.get("http://localhost:8080/ords/hr/rest-v3/item/Sugar", (error, response, body) => {

    if (error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }

    console.log(response.body);
});
```

It is giving below output which is correct.

```
{"items":[{"itemid":101,"itemname":"Sugar","itemcost":32.5}],"hasMore":false,"limit":0,"offset":0,"count":1,"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://localhost:8080/ords/hr/rest-v3/item/Sugar"},{"rel":"describedby","href":"http://localhost:8080/ords/hr/metadata-catalog/rest-v3/item/item"}]}
```

How can I access only `itemcost`, not entire body. I am new to node so not familiar with many things.
Can you please help me on that.

Comment: You can do something like `response.body.items[0].itemcost`

Comment: could you paste your output instead of Image. ?

Comment: @MjZac thanks but it is giving error....items[0] not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it can help you.

```
var Request = require("request");
Request.get("http://localhost:8080/ords/hr/rest-v3/item/Sugar", (error, response, body) => {

if (error) {
return console.dir(error);
}
let jsonData = JSON.parse(response.body);
let obj= new Object(jsonData);

 obj.items.forEach(itemChild => {
     let cost=itemChild.itemcost;
     console.log(cost);
 })

});
```

Comment: I am getting error. "can not read property forEach of undefined"

Comment: Error..itemchild.map is not a function

Comment: Bro..can you also help me with Syntax error. I put flower bracket and semicolon but it is not getting compiled

Comment: TypeError:projObj.map is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210208/discussion-between-onkar-tiwari-and-suman-dash).

Comment: Bro..does it make any difference if I consume https URL or http?

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate the `response.body.items` and get the costs of all items in the `items` array like this,

```
var Request = require("request");
Request.get("http://localhost:8080/ords/hr/rest-v3/item/Sugar", (error, response, body) => {

    if (error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }

    console.log(response.body);
    const itemCosts = response.body.items.map(item => item.itemcost);
    console.log(itemCosts);
});
```

Comment: I am getting error "TypeError: can not read property 'map of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Considering your input you can simply do this:

```
    let input  = {
    "items": [
        {
            "itemid": 101,
            "itemname": "Sugar",
            "itemcost": 32.5
        }
    ],
    "hasMore": false,
    "limit": 0,
    "offset": 0,
    "count": 1,
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/ords/hr/rest-v3/item/Sugar"
        },
        {
            "rel": "describedby",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/ords/hr/metadata-catalog/rest-v3/item/item"
        }
    ]
};

let json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input));
json.items.map(item =>{
    console.log(item.itemcost)
})
```

You can find running solution [here](https://repl.it/repls/GrouchyAnxiousProjects)